# Report failures in TestNG framework

Tags: maven, testng

I have developed TestNG framework and implemented Maven

When I run the script, the results are generated and in the target folder, when I open index.html, all the scripts are displayed as Pass though it failed.

I  have used java verifications (reporter.log)

Can someone suggest me on how to change the java verifications to TestNG to view the failures?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Reporter.log is just for logging statements in the report.  You need to use assertions to do your verifications.  Try out the [Assert](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/Assert.html) class in Testng.